# Copy output table of pivottable from chosen excel file and paste it into a place in open word document, triggered from existing userform in word doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, pivot-table

I have a word document with an existing userform in it that takes values from the userform and puts them into content controls throughout the document.

Currently users have to locate a specific excel document (different document and location each time), copy the output table from a pivot table on a particular sheet and paste it into a specific location in the word document after the macro has filled in the content controls.

I now want to add the ability for this to be done automatically, have file explorer pop up and allow the user to navigate to a specific excel file and have the word macro then copy the output table from the pivot table within the chosen excel file and paste it into a specific location in the word document.

So Far I have been able to get word to open file explorer and allow me to navigate and select a particular excel sheet and move the cursor to the correct point in the document but when the code tries to paste the pivot table I get the error "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" and the debugger highlights the `pt.TableRange1.Paste` line.

Any advice, greatly appreciated - this is the code I have currently. The basis of this was taken from another document hence the dim's and sets but not sure if I might end up needing some so have left them in.

The name of the pivottable is "PivotTable3" in PivotTable options in the excel document (I never made it).

```
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Dim j As Long

Dim tbl As Table

Dim openDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim MyExcel As Excel.Application
Dim MyWB As Excel.Workbook
Set MyExcel = New Excel.Application

Dim tmpIntStr As Variant
Dim tmpInt As Integer

Dim cc As ContentControl

Dim borderrange As Range

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
openDialog.Filters.Clear
openDialog.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"

' --------------------------------------------------------------------

' Use Open dialog to get the RA file path
If openDialog.Show Then
    txtRAPath = openDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Set MyWB = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(txtRAPath)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

' Check that the RA is a compatible version

Worksheets("PriceTable").Activate

Set pt = Worksheets("PriceTable").PivotTables("PivotTable3")

pt.TableRange1.Copy

' Move cursor to correct place

For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
If cc.Tag = "PT" Then
cc.Range.Select
Exit For
End If
Next

pt.TableRange1.Paste

MyWB.Close
```

Comment: `Worksheets("XXX").PivotTables(3)` addresses the third pivot table on the sheet. Are you sure that there are 3 pivot tables on the worksheet? You may do better by using the name rather than the index number, something like `Worksheets("XXX").PivotTables("PivotTable3")`

Comment: I have tried your suggestions @TimothyRylatt and that seemed to work (THANK YOU) but I am now getting a new error "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" and the debugger highlights the pt.TableRange1.Paste line. Any ideas?

Comment: According to your question you are to to ***copy*** the pivot table, not paste it. I assume you should be pasting it into the content control, in which case you would use something like `cc.Range.Paste`